# How jQuery creates DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery I can create a real DOM node, but it is not located in the DOM. So how does jQuery do it? My guess that it might create it first in the DOM and then removes it.

```
// here `el` is not a jQuery object
el = $('<div></div>')[0];


console.log(el.tagName);  // "DIV"
console.log(el.nodeType); // "1"
```

Comment: Why don't you debug it with an inspector and see for yourself? (And then return to tell us)

Comment: It actually reads the string to parse it

Comment: @Itay Will Inspector give me the history of a node?

Comment: You can call the `debugger;` before the first command and start `F11` from there. It will show you the flow step by step.

Comment: It's not like jQuery's technique is a big secret, the code is all right there for you to see in [jquery.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js), or there's [James Padolsey's jQuery source viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a miracle, when you pass `<div></div>` to jQuery it matches it against the regular expression and tag check conditions like below

```
if ( selector.charAt(0) === "<" && selector.charAt( selector.length - 1 ) === ">" && selector.length >= 3 
 // Assume that strings that start and end with <> are HTML and skip the regex check
 match = [ null, selector, null ];
}
```

else matches it with below regular expressions to find out the element in the selector string.

```
    /^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/
```

Once it find the element, then jQuery uses `document.createElement("stripped Tag from selector")` and will return the element with necessary jQuery methods added.

I would say until and unless you need it for your requirement, use `document.createElement('div')` instead of `$('<div></div>')`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe jQuery uses `document.createElement()` to create the specified element.  This method  creates the node and returns it, but does not attach it to the DOM.  See the related [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) for details on how it works.

Comment: There are 14 occurrences in jQuery 1.10.2 that calls `document.createElement` and I fail to see any arguments passing to it, so how can jQuery create elements dynamically in that way?

Comment: @jasonslyvia There is an argument passed into every occurrence of this function call in the source code of jQuery.

Comment: @Adam but it's static, not a variable, how can jQuery tell which element the user want to create?

Comment: @jasonslyvia By parsing the html. Look at the definition of the function parseHTML

Comment: @jasonslyvia The argument should be variable. The specific call being used can be found in `parseHTML()` as [`context.createElement( parsed[1] )`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.10.2/src/core.js#L517).

Comment: yeah i find it, my mistake. i only search for `document.createElement`

Answer (score 1):

it uses the `createElement` function which does create a DOM object that is not part of the page. - Just read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement to create DOM objects. For text nodes see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode

This is for new items

You can attach it to existing DOM items (part of the page) with appendChild - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

To find such items use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName etc.

Comment: @Itay - Why not an answer as it points to where to gain the information. Should I just post that information verbatim? Well at least I do not ask a question then answer it myself and give myself a tick for the right answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think if you edited to read something like "Use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) to create DOM objects that are not yet part of the page..." then it would be a clearer explanation _and_ a link to the more detailed method explanation.

Comment: @ltay - Are you happy now?

Comment: @EdHeal "*Edited to pacify the readers*" Not the best way to accept criticism. Including links in your answer is definitely good; but they [should be supplementary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/15031). If you just want to offer them mostly on their own, post them in a comment. Also, [answering your own question is actually promoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12519/15031). It has a badge. And, "*Ask a Question*" even allows posting an Answer at the same time. Though, for the record, such posts can't be accepted right away, giving others have a chance to post as well.

Comment: Idk what happened there, I swear my computer went spastic for a sec. I had a good answer lined up, it was slow, got cut off, downvoted the wrong answer, etc. I must be tired, but I like this answer the best, so I'll edit it to include some of the links I was going to include.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - Ok - Got a couple of outstanding question that I will answer just to gain a badge or two

Comment: @EdHeal Feel free. [If others agree with your answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner), then you'll have earned them. Along with some rep.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - I am not an actor and will not pat myself on the back.

Comment: @EdHeal The point of the feature is to allow for sharing a specific lesson learned so others can hopefully learn from it as well. It's not to be self-gratifying; though, certainly, some will find that in it. But, that's why it requires others' upvotes -- the answer has to actually help more than just the author. And, if you should use the feature legitimately, then it'll be a contribution, not an act.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - I was thinking of the Oscars or the Baftas. but why not just edit the question?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery creates an element but it doesn't add it to DOM automatically. 
I order to see it in the DOM you have to add it to DOM 
you could use $().after, $().appendTo and so on...

Comment: You've just said what the OP already says. Your answer does not say how does it work.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery parse the HTML string using regular expressions and creates a dom element using the code below:

```
parseHTML: function( data, context, keepScripts ) {
    if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
        return null;
    }
    if ( typeof context === "boolean" ) {
        keepScripts = context;
        context = false;
    }
    context = context || document;

    var parsed = rsingleTag.exec( data ),
        scripts = !keepScripts && [];

    // Single tag
    if ( parsed ) {
        return [ context.createElement( parsed[1] ) ];
    }

    parsed = jQuery.buildFragment( [ data ], context, scripts );
    if ( scripts ) {
        jQuery( scripts ).remove();
    }
    return jQuery.merge( [], parsed.childNodes );
}
```

It may be easier to inspect the code at this page.

http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.parseHTML